# R - Constructing matrix, simulate probabilty, contain in new matrix and display on histogram

Tags: r, matrix

Trying to teach myself R. Using problem from a friend which requires me to:

- Construct a matrix with 5000 rows and 20 columns
- Each column represents toss from coin #1 to #20
- Each column must represent 50 coin tosses.
- Probability goes from .05 to 1 of getting heads from coin 1 in column 1  to coin 20 in column 20

I'm not quite sure how to loop this or the most efficient way to go about it. Do I need to go up by .05 increments?

- Find the mean and the variance of each column and
  hold the results in a 20*2 matrix.

-Put the first 8 columns into histograms using 2*4 matrix

-Have each main title be the coin #.

Here's the code I have so far. I think I'm on the right track in some areas. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

```
test<-matrix(nrow=5000,ncol=20)
for(i in 1:20){

test<-matrix(nrow=5000,ncol=20,data=
c(rbinom(n=5000, size=50, prob=.05),rbinom(n=5000, size=50, prob=.10)
} ??




testdescstats<-matrix(nrow=20,ncol=2)
for(i in 1:20){

testdescstats[i,1]<-mean(test[,i])
testdescstats[i,2]<-var(test[,i])
}


split.screen(c(2,4))
for(i in 1:8){
screen(i)
hist(test[,i],paste0 graph titles?
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This is not a great first question. Each question should focus on a single programming task. Make it clear where you are having difficulty. Show what code you tried and describe how it failed and clearly state the desired output. Don't just dump a grocery list of tasks you want others to do for you. See [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you really just want us to do this for you? Not sure that's the best to do a learning exercise, but here you go

```
#create matrix
prob <- seq(.05, 1, length.out=20)
x <- sapply(prob, function(p) rbinom(5000, 50, p))

#summarize
r <- t(apply(x, 2, function(z) c(mean(z), var(z))))

#plot histograms
layout(matrix(1:8, nrow=2, byrow=T))
for(i in 1:8) hist(x[,i], main=i)
```

[image]

Comment: I will make sure I go about making my questions more detailed next time. Sorry. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

`for` loops are verboten in R but for this instance they are pretty quick

Create a logical matrix (`heads = TRUE`, `tails = FALSE`)

```
mat <- matrix(TRUE, ncol = 20, nrow = 5000)
```

Simulate coin tosses with the weight of the coin (`prob`) determined by the column

```
for (i in 1:20) 
  mat[,i] <- sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), size = 5000, prob = c(i/20, 1 - i/20), replace = TRUE)
```

Use `apply` to obtain the column means and variances. Your values may vary.

```
apply(mat, 2, mean)
 [1] 0.0506 0.0980 0.1520 0.2046 0.2496 0.2996 0.3460 0.3962 0.4504 0.5110 0.5528 0.6108 0.6560 0.7024 0.7528 0.8120 0.8496
[18] 0.8996 0.9498 1.0000

apply(mat, 2, var)
 [1] 0.04804925 0.08841368 0.12892178 0.16277139 0.18733731 0.20988182 0.22632927 0.23927341 0.24758936 0.24992899
[11] 0.24726161 0.23777091 0.22570914 0.20907606 0.18612939 0.15268654 0.12780540 0.09033791 0.04768950 0.00000000
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. This is quite a bit different from what I've seen. Do you have any good online sources for R tutorials?